# Simulation of LogNormal process for an asset pricing

Tags: probability-or-statistics, simulation, finance

I'm new to Mathematica programming, so forgive my rather unsophisticated question.

I need to simulate 5000 "walks" of a process value (of a stock) that starts from its current value, at `t0`, and ends in `T` (expiration date of an option). The stocks follow a lognormal process. The process in question must have mean `(r - [Sigma]^2/2)` and standard deviation `([Sigma] Sqrt[T])`. After that, I need to  calculate the mean of the 5000 final values that, probably, will correspond to the expected value `(E^Q) [Subscript[S, T]]`. All of this to find the price of a call option using:

```
Subscript[C, t] = E^(-r (T - t)) ((E^Q) [Subscript[S, T]] - K)
```

and find the value in `t` of my call option.

In theory I know all of this but practically can not do anything. Can someone help me?

Comment: If you're interested in doing option pricing I would recommend using the [FinancialDerivative](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialDerivative.html) function for instance `FinancialDerivative[{"European", "Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 50.00, 
  "Expiration" -> 1},  {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.5, 
  "CurrentPrice" -> 50, "Dividend" -> 0.05}]`. I think that will do the full Black-Scholes equation for you and give you better results.

Comment: Massimiliano, do you mean (sigma Sqrt[T]) to be the *variance* or the *standard deviation* of the underlying normal distribution? I realize that you explicitly say variance, but your usage of sigma seems to be more congruent with a standard deviation instead.

Comment: Also relevant to your problem: [(25113)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25113/27951); [(77400)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77400/27951)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

This should generate 5000 samples from the distribution you specified, once you plug in the values of `sigma` and `t`:

```
RandomVariate[
 LogNormalDistribution[r - sigma^2/2, sigma Sqrt[t]],
 5000
]
```

For instance (I just made up numbers here for mean and sigma):

```
samples = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1 - 0.5^2/2, 0.5 Sqrt[2]], 1000];
Histogram[samples]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The second argument of the `LogNormalDistribution` is the `StandardDeviation` of the underlying `NormalDistribution` not its `Variance`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for pointing that out. I realized that I "interpreted" the original user's expression, rather than taking it literally, when he said that variance is `([Sigma] Sqrt[T])`: from the way that he used Sigma, it seemed to me that he was referring to it as the *standard deviation* of the underlying distribution, even though he referred to it as the variance, but let me ask the OP and I'll amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for the swift response =). Now, I can't use the FinancialDerivate because I have to make a "particular" estimatio changing  the probability  (from P to Q using the martingale theory). for (sigma Sqrt [T]) I mean standard deviation, excuse for inaccuracy. now last thing, the simulation as I do? I should do 10,000 simulations of a walk of a price, starting from price 32.68 in t0 with and then calculate the average of the final values that, probably, should be the real price.

Comment: @MassimilianoPiane I am afraid that I know nothing about finance and related models, but if I were you, I'd rephrase the problem in detail by editing your original question, maybe providing a example as well (even if it's made up).

Comment: ok! thank you anyway =D

Answer (score 1):

```
With[{t0 = 0, tend = 1, σ = 0.8, r = .01, S0 = 100, Κ = 110}, 
 data = RandomFunction[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0, σ, S0], {t0, tend, 1/12}, 5000];
 Exp[-r (tend - t0)] Mean[Max[#, 0] & /@ (data["LastValues"] - Κ)]]
(* 27.5607 *)

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comparing this with Black-Scholes:

```
d1[s_, x_, r_, t_, σ_] := (Log[s/x] + (r + 1/2 σ^2) t)/(σ Sqrt[t])
d2[s_, x_, r_, t_, σ_] := d1[s, x, r, t, σ] - σ Sqrt[t]
c[s_, x_, r_, t_, σ_] :=  s CDF[NormalDistribution[], d1[s, x, r, t, σ]] - 
   x E^(-r t) CDF[NormalDistribution[], d2[s, x, r, t, σ]]
p[s_, x_, r_, t_, σ_] := x E^(-r t) (1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[], d2[s, x, r, t, σ]]) - 
   s (1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[], d1[s, x, r, t, σ]])

With[{t0 = 0, tend = 1, σ = 0.8, r = .01, S0 = 100, Κ = 110}, 
 data = RandomFunction[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0, σ, S0], {t0, tend, 1/12}, 5000];
   c[S0, Κ, r, tend - t0, σ]}]
(* 28.1904 *)
```

or, with the built-in `FinancialDerivative`:

```
With[{t0 = 0, tend = 1, σ = 0.8, r = .01, S0 = 100, Κ = 110},
 FinancialDerivative[{"European", "Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> Κ, 
   "Expiration" -> 1},  {"InterestRate" -> r, 
   "Volatility" -> σ, "CurrentPrice" -> 100, "Dividend" -> 0}]
 ]
(* 28.1904 *)
```